# Jenkins send slack notification when slave agent goes offline

Tags: jenkins, slack

I have a local Jenkins instance ( version 2.164 ) and I have slack notifications plugin set up for pipelines and job results, but I would also like to receive notifications to my slack channel when one of my slave nodes goes offline/online.

Is there some plugin or configuration I'm missing for this please? Ive searched through the plugin catalogue and browsed through google, and all the configuration menus I can think of, but can't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin to send email notification when nodes down or up.

I also tried to find, but [Mail Watcher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mail+Watcher+Plugin) is the only choice, so using this plugin and then connect to slack with [Slack Email plugin](https://slack.com/intl/en-kr/slack-tips/send-email-to-slack).

With Email plugin, you can send direct email to slack channel, therefore node up/down notifications can be sent to slack channel.